# change profile picture in edit profile as well as side bar also in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

How to change profile image in edit profile page when i change in edit profile page it must reflect to my side bar also at the same time

In my case i am able to change my profile image in edit profile using cordova plugin but it can not reflect in my side bar it shows previous image any one can help???

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) for that.

This is what i do for it.
After changing profile picture in page, I update that profile page to nativestorage and then publish event that updates profile pic in side menu.

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('uImage', "Image Url goes here");
this.events.publish('profileUpdated');
```

And in the app.component.ts:

```
 this.events.subscribe('profileUpdated', () => {

        this.nativeStorage.getItem('uImage')
        .then( (data)=> {
          this.uImage = data;
          console.log(this.userData);
        },(error)=> {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

And in the app.html where menu is displayed,

```
 <img src="{{uImage}}">
```